# Error using static string in Attribute. Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderNames not a const anymore

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

In a new ASP.NET Core 5 project, when defining a Header Attributer filter for Swashbuckle:

```
[RequestHeaderMatchesMediaType(
    Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderNames.Accept, "mytypename")]
```

Exception:

> CS0182 An attribute argument must be a constant expression

Caused by [dotnet HeaderNames source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Http/Headers/src/HeaderNames.cs):

```
public static readonly string Accept = "Accept";
```

Attributes complilation demand a const, so I've copied the [original aspnet Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers/HeaderNames.cs) constants.

There is a discussion about why the change was made on [dotnet aspnet core github #12439](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/12439), but the question I have is:

**How do I use a `static readonly` in an attribute?**

Comment: "How do I use a static readonly in an Attribute?" - you can't. It's simply not a compile-time constant. (Suppose that were declared as `public static readonly string Accept = DateTime.Now.ToString();`)

Comment: From aspnet team, reason for change away from const: "'const' values would be embedded into each assembly".

Comment: Well, it's more than just that - it's the *impact* of that, in terms of the validity of quick equality checks via ReferenceEquals. But your question didn't ask about the motivation (you've linked to that already). You just can't do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Comment: I undid the solution announcement edit. Please check whether you still need the side-edit of the word in the title.

Comment: Thx @jon-skeet. The team has given a fair justification for making the change, and I accept that, the outcome for my situation necessitates making a local copy of the constants, unless there is another approach ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, you cannot use `static readonly` fields in attributes. The reason for this is that attributes need *compile-time* constant values, while `static readonly` fields are only created at run-time.

The linked issue (and there are others for similar changes) already discuss why they made the change from constant values to static fields. In the end, the reason is irrelevant to you in this situation: You want to use the header name in the attribute.

The only solution here is to simply copy the value, and you can do that directly like this:

```cs
[RequestHeaderMatchesMediaType("Accept", "mytypename")]
```

If you end up doing a check like this repeatedly, then it may make sense to introduce a constant yourself, so that you can reuse the same value, and e.g. be safe against misspellings in some cases. Introducing a constant also allows you to use IDE tools to find its usages. However, defining a constant will *not* impact the result. During compilation, constant values will be copied in and the original `const` declaration “disappears”.

```cs
public class Constants
{
    public const AcceptHeaderName = "Accept";
    public const MyTypeName = "mytypename";
}
```

```cs
[RequestHeaderMatchesMediaType(Constants.AcceptHeaderName, Constants.MyTypeName)]
```